# PHP dynamic multidimensional array creation

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I'm scanning a folder and it's subfolders for files with PHP. I want to store the folders and files in a PHP array so I can create a treeview in another page. This is the format I get files paths in:

- /home/project/index.php
- /home/project/folder/myclass.php
- /home/project/folder/myclass2.php
- /home/project/folder/subfolder/anotherclass.php

I want to get these files in the following array:

- [home][project] = array('index.php')
- [home][project][folder] = array(myclass.php, myclass2.php)
- [home][project][folder][subfolder] = array(anotherclass.php)

Note that the folder structure can change at any point. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the built in (SPL) [`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class and a simple recursive function.

An *untested* example:

```
public function directoryToArray($directoryPath)
{
  $items = new DirectoryIterator($directoryPath);
  $data  = array();

  foreach($items as $item) {
    $name = $item->getFileName();

    if ($item->isFile()) {
      $data[] = $name;
    } 
    else if ($item->isDir()) {
      $data[$name] = directoryToArray($item->getPath());
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this method, but I would like to know how to convert a flat array to a multidimensional array. This would be the workaround that would work, but it's not the answer I'm looking for, thanks.